# Getting corresponding values from two different objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have returned an object from an ajax call that is the combination of two different arrays' of objects. One is Jobs and the second is the corresponding Customer Records for those jobs. The returned object is formatted like so..

```
  { "jobs" : [
         {jobID: 1,
          jobLocation: here
         },
         {jobID: 2,
          jobLocation: there
         }
    ],
    "customers" : [
         {customerID:1,
          customerName:Tom
         },
         {customerID:2,
          customerName:Sally
         }
    ]
   }
```

The items in the job array are sequentially related to the customers in the customer array. (i.e. the first customer owns the first job) How can I iterate or parse then iterate over this object to make list objects`<li>`'s that have are composed of a field from the jobs array and a field from the corresponding object of the customers array? thank you

Comment: What's your desired result looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain, old for-loop might do the job:

```
var customers = obj.customers;
var jobs = obj.jobs;
var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
   var customer = customers[i];
   var job = jobs[i];

   var $li = $("<li></li>").text(customer.customerName + " - " + job.jobLocation);
   $li.appendTo($ul);
}

$("#result").append($ul);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/XpQms/

Comment: whoop. Thanks winSharp. I needed that, I was wayyyyyy over complicating things